# xml parser fileNotFound error

Tags: java, ajax, xml, xml-parsing

So I am having a directory with xml files only and I am trying to iterate through it. The problem I encountered is that whenever I try parse a file I am getting fileNotFound exception.

The code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    File dir = new File(".\\xmlFileGoHere");
    File[] directoryListing = dir.listFiles();

    for(File fileName : directoryListing) {
        String path = fileName.getAbsolutePath();
        Document xmlDoc = getDocument(path);
    }
}

private static Document getDocument(String docString) {
    try {
        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        factory.setIgnoringComments(true);
        factory.setValidating(true);

        DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
        return builder.parse(new InputSource(docString));
    } 
    catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

}

At first I thouht the path I was sending was not correct and to check that I changed the code to:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    File dir = new File(".\\xmlFileGoHere");
    File[] directoryListing = dir.listFiles();

    for(File fileName : directoryListing) {
        String path = fileName.getAbsolutePath();
        File file = new File(path);
        System.out.println(file.exists());
    }
}
```

The code above always returns true.

I am on windows so I have not taken into account permissions.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass in a URI, not a file path to the `InputSource` constructor so change `getDocument(path)` to `getDocument(fileName.toURI().toString())`.

As an alternative, as you have a `File` already and there is a `parse` overload taking a `File` you can change the signature to `private static Document getDocument(File input)` and the code to `return builder.parse(input);`.

Comment: That suggest you are trying to parse an XML document referencing a DTD file which does not exist on your system at that path.